# Photon trapped inside an acrylic cube

Tags: visible-light, photons, reflection

Suppose a single photon is trapped in an acrylic cube surrounded by air and bounces around inside the cube at a 45 degree angle of incidence/reflection. Since the critical angle for the acrylic-air interface is 41.8 degrees, the photon will undergo total internal reflection. If the photon never gets absorbed or scattered by the acrylic will it bounce around inside the cube forever? In other words, would there be any way for the photon to escape the cube other than through absorption or scattering by the atoms in the acrylic?

Answer (score 0):

Total internat reflection is not that "total". Evanescent waves should form close to the surface of the cube and can become a dissipation mechanism. On top of that, photon is a quantum particle, which, in your case, is confined into a 3D box with walls of finite thickness, hence, tunneling is possible. In general, there is no real system in the world, that can be 100% isolated in Newtonian sense. Even if you exclude scattering and photo-absorption+all listed above, you can talk about collective excitations in the polymer (plasmons, polaritons etc.). I am sure I have not exhausted the list...